# How do I parse a remote web page and extract strings from a list of <span> fields

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have got a problem with printing the list of strings from the arrays. I'm using the $test variable to print the list of strings. When I'm trying to print the strings from the arrays, I will get the short strings with one letter from each array which I don't want that. I want to print the full strings from each array using with $count to count the values.

Here is the input:

```
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSLLLLLLLLLLLLL
LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAADDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLLLL
LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

When I try this code:

```
   <?php
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
   $errmsg_arr = array();
   $errflag = true;

   function getState($string)
   {
     $ex = explode(" ",$string);
     return $ex[1];
   }
   $baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.myownsite.com/get-listing.php'
   );

   $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
   $domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
   $domdoc->recover=true;
   @$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
   $links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
   $i = 0;
   $count = 0;
   for ($i = 1; $i < 70; $i++)
   {
     $time_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");
     $programme_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='title".$i."']");
   }

   $programme_title = array();
   foreach($programme_arr as $programme) 
   {
     $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
     $programme_title[] = $programme1;
   }

   foreach($time_arr as $time)
   {
     //$test = implode(' ', $programme_title);
     //$tester[] = $test;
     //echo $tester;

     $test = implode(' ', $programme_title);
     echo $test[$count];
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Do you know how I can print the full strings from each array without printing one letter 
when using with $test variable?

**Edit: Here is the output:**

```
Sister Act Sister Act 2: Back in the Habit Mamma Mia!Forrest Gump(D,L,V,S) 
The Blind SideJoel OsteenJoyce Meyer: Enjoying Everyday LifeShaun T's 
Focus T25Summer Sexy With T25!Total Gym for $14.95Dr. Ordon's Secret!
Sleep Better!Steam And Spray The Dirt Away ... SHARK Style!Shaun T's Focus T25
Airbrushed BeautyJoseph PrinceLife Today With James Robison - Mark Driscoll 1
Joyce Meyer: Enjoying Everyday LifeShaun T's Focus T25That '70s Show - I Love Cake
That '70s Show - Sleepover That '70s Show - Eric Gets Suspended That '70s Show - 
Red's BirthdayStill Standing - Still Thankful700 Club InteractiveThe 700 ClubGil
more Girls - Haunted Leg8 Simple Rules -
```

and so on...

Edit: Here is the update code:

```
   $programme_title = array();
   foreach($programme_arr as $programme)
   {
     $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
     $programme_title[] = $programme1;
   }


   foreach($time_arr as $time)
   {
     echo $programme_title[$count];
     //$test = implode(' ', $programme_title);
     //echo $test[$count];
   }
```

Comment: `$test[$count];` — what do you think you're doing here!?

Comment: @upvoter WTH?! Do you even understand what is being asked?

Comment: You're basically doing `echo $test[x];` multiple times, where does `$count` come from?

Comment: I guess what we see here is the concatenation of all first letters of all available titles. Because php is using the string as array and so prints only the first character. This might get clearer when executing a 'print_r(programmme1)' within the loop after asigning the value.

Comment: @TheBlueDog please see the update code in my first post.

Comment: @user3620904: Yeah, and you are not incrementing `$count` anywhere, it's always 0.

Comment: @user3620904: please insert a the print_r(programme1) in the loop after assigning its value and add the output to this post.

Comment: @tswaehn I have updated. Please see my update post.

Comment: Thanks! I usually use a <pre> code </pre>. To make it a little more readable. Because we do not see the the different loops here please update precisely as shown by your browser, including the variables.

Comment: @tswaehn i'm sorry, but I don't get what you mean? this is the only code I have already provided. However, when I use the `print_r($programme1);` in the `foreach $programme_arr` loop, it works fine and it also works fine outside the loop. When I try to use the `print_r($test);` in the `foreach $time_arr` loop, I will get an error 500 internal server error. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: BTW, you did not define **$xpath** - what is this?

Comment: @tswaehn it is using for getting the element from the tag called <span id="title"> i have print the list of strings which it works fine, however, when i try to use foreach($time_arr as $time)
   { $test = $programme_title; echo $test i will get the output `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`. Any idea how i can print the strings using with echo?

Comment: It is not only the printout which is wrong. It is also how you import the data. there are more than one mistakes in your code. (1) you did not define **$xpath** before you use it. (2) you did not increment **$count**. (3) It is not clear if there are exactly "70" items you can parse. -- to fix all we need to go through one by one.

Comment: well when I try to use `foreach $time_arr { echo $programme_title;` it will print the list of same strings without the `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray` How do you print each different strings from each array using with `echo $programme_title;`? if you need to see my website link, here it is: http://67.23.248.61/~ytestbox/allchannels_fix.php. the list of strings should be like this: http://67.23.248.61/~ytestbox/get-listing.php?channels=ABC%20FAMILY&id=101

Comment: I provided the code below with only necessary changes. Please note it is far from being nice to read. Also having one array in a **foreach** and at the same time loop through the other array with **count** is far from being a good solution. -- but it works.

Comment: BTW - in your code there is also a bracket **}** to much at the end.

Comment: @tswaehn thank you very much for posted the fixed code, I can see it is working great now. I have gave you the vote so please feel free to do the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
 $time_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");
```

before it is even defined. You need to define ***$xpath*** as parser. Something like this

```
@$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);

$xpath = DOMXPath( $domdoc );
```

then you will be able to request data from the document.

Now here is what might give you the result as expected. I did use the provided URL

```
 <?php
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
   $errmsg_arr = array();
   $errflag = true;

   function getState($string)
   {
     $ex = explode(" ",$string);
     return $ex[1];
   }

   // read the remote file
   $baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://some-server.com/get-listing.php?channels=ABC%20FAMILY&id=101');

   // create the parser
   $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
   $domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
   $domdoc->recover=true;
   @$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($domdoc);

   //$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');

   $i = 0;
   $count = 0;
   for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
     $time_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");
     $programme_arr[] = $xpath->query('//span[@id="title'.$i.'"]');
   }

   $programme_title = array();
   foreach($programme_arr as $programme) {
     $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
     $programme_title[] = $programme1;
   }

   //

   echo "<pre>";

   print_r( $programme_title );

   echo "</pre>";

   $count = 0;
   foreach($time_arr as $time){
     //$test = implode(' ', $programme_title);
     //$tester[] = $test;
     //echo $tester;
     echo $time->item(0)->nodeValue." ";
     echo $programme_title[$count++]."<br>";
   }


 ?>
```

it returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sister Act 2: Back in the Habit
    [1] => Mamma Mia!
    [2] => Forrest Gump(D,L,V,S)
    [3] => The Blind Side
)

1:30 PM Sister Act 2: Back in the Habit
3:30 PM Mamma Mia!
6:00 PM Forrest Gump(D,L,V,S)
9:00 PM The Blind Side
```